# building from source code fails

Tags: gcc, configure

I'm trying to build some software from scratch on a full installation of Slackware64 14.2. I follow the instructions in readme

```
 ./autogen.sh # only needed if building from git repo
 CFLAGS="-march=native" ./configure
# Use -march=native if building for a single machine
make
```

I cloned it from git then did issued autogen, which outputed:

```
configure.ac:16: installing './compile'
configure.ac:4: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:4: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:6: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:6: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
```

Then after that I issued the next command as I build it on a single machine but it resulted in an error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/xtd8865/data/builds/mine/cpuminer-multi/cpuminer-multi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

As I said, it's a full slackware version:

```
gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-slackware-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/man --infodir=/usr/info --enable-shared --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,go,java,lto,objc --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-objc-gc --with-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib64/python2.7/site-packages --enable-libstdcxx-dual-abi --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --enable-lto --disable-install-libiberty --with-gnu-ld --verbose --enable-java-home --with-java-home=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib64/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib64/jvm/jvm-exports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar=/root/slackware64-current/source/d/gcc/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-gtktest --disable-multilib --target=x86_64-slackware-linux --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-slackware-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

So I'm not sure why it cannot create executables. I issued those commands as standard user (tried as root as well but no luck either). Why is it failing?

The output of the config.log is here
http://pastebin.com/QUqHW6zQ

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

```
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='*-march-native*'
```

which for whatever reason contains wildcards.  The log does not show an earlier use than its attempt to use it in gcc, so:

- either there is a scripting error in what you downloaded or
- you have an environment variable setting which is confusing the script.

To see a scripting error, you'd have to turn on the shell trace (adding a `set -x` after the first line) and (it goes to the standard error) capture the output and read a **much** longer log...

Comment: Thanks - That's the set -x output: http://pastebin.com/De2WtiHP